# How to add a custom resolution for a Win10 Virtualbox VM

Tags: virtualbox, display-resolution

I have installed Windows 10 on a Virtualbox machine, and it works fine. However, the resolution is not the same as my laptop's, so the display is very small. When I change it in the display settings, the highest resolution is 1600x1200, whereas my resolution is 1920x1080. Is there any way to add a custom resolution? Another problem I face is that my mouse does not go above a certain level. For example, in the 1600x1200 resolution, I am unable to click the close window button. My mouse becomes my native mouse after a certain height. Is there anyway to fix these issues? Thanks in advance.